# How do rekonq's vi shortcuts work?

Tags: kde, vim, rekonq

As a vim user, I was pleased to discover a checkbox in Rekonq's (Kubuntu's web browser) settings that enables vi-like shortcuts. However, checking it doesn't seem to have any effect, at least with the shortcuts I know. I can't seem to find any documentation about this anywhere, in the help files or on google. What are these shortcuts, exactly, and how can I get them to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am in Kubuntu 12.04 and they work ok. They used to work on Konqueror too. By vi-shortcuts its understood that the "hjkl" keys  work, not <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> or any of the editing options, just the navigator keys, but combined with `focus follow mouse` activated its a powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks. When I posted this, they weren't working for some reason, and this feature wasn't documented.